# How do I make toggle button stick with div while it's sliding? Vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I have a div that slides (out to left/in from left) when the toggle button is clicked on. I'm using Vue.js's transition component to handle the slide animation. The slide animation for the div works as intended, but my problem is that the toggle button doesn't stick with the div while it's sliding (out/in). Both are nested within a container.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/chataolauj/pen/jOrOWpL

```css
#app {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 28%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;

  #event-list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  .toggle-button {
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow: 3px -1px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    outline: none;

    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }
  }
}

.slide-in-out-enter-active {
  animation: slide-in-out 0.5s reverse;
}

.slide-in-out-leave-active {
  animation: slide-in-out 0.5s;
}

@keyframes slide-in-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
      <div id="container">
        <transition name="slide-in-out">
          <div v-if="toggle" id="event-list">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In imperdiet ante id finibus molestie. Mauris pharetra vel est id dictum. In varius, mi in interdum dignissim, nulla erat congue erat, viverra consequat felis libero vel sem. Pellentesque vel ex tristique, ultrices tortor vel, consequat erat. Nulla ornare porttitor nisl.</p>
          </div>
        </transition>
        <button @click="toggle = !toggle" class="toggle-button">Toggle
        </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: @Cuong Le Ngoc's answer did satisfy my question, but seeing the texting wrapping while the panel is "sliding" makes it seem more like a "shrink" transition than a "slide" transition. It's a dealbreaker for me. I'm trying to emulate Google Maps sliding panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation with `width` instead of `transform: translateX(...)` and use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to prevent text overflow:

```
#event-list {
  ...
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And:

```
@keyframes slide-in-out {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cuong97cc1/pen/XWKWKNK)

**EDIT:** You can use `margin-left` instead of `width` if you prefer slide transition

```
@keyframes slide-in-out {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cuong97cc1/pen/XWKWyxp)

Comment: It does what I asked for, so thanks for the answer, but I don't like how the text is being wrapped while the panel is sliding. It just makes it seem more like a shrink transition than a sliding transition. I know I'm being really nitpicky here, but it's a dealbreaker for me from a UX design perspective. What I'm trying to emulate is Google Maps panel.

Comment: It's better than animating with width, but I still can't get over the fact that the text is moving while the transitioning is happening.